# How to find sector from x and y coordinate in a circle

Tags: java, geometry

*Note that most numbers I will use are just examples as it needs to be dynamic*

I am trying to create a circle with a dynamic height, width and circle sectors using UTF Full Block icon (= █) *(these are then used in Minecraft holograms, which is centered, so there are not a bunch of spaces to center it)*.

Let's say I for example have a circle of 25x25 (diameter of 25) with 12 (nearly equal) sectors, each of these sectors would get a different color, the center of the circle is (0, 0).
How would I be able to "divide" this circle into sectors and put a sector ID (0-11 for example) on a coordinate?

Below you see the code I use currently, the getSectionNumber method does not work at all and can probably be ignored:

```java
public class HologramCircle {

    private final int height;
    private final int width;

    public HologramCircle(final int height, final int width) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public List<String> getLines() {
        final float width_r = (float) width / 2;
        final float height_r = (float) height / 2;
        final float ratio = width_r / height_r;

        final double maxblocks_x;
        final double maxblocks_y;

        if ((width_r * 2) % 2 == 0) {
            maxblocks_x = Math.ceil(width_r - .5) * 2 + 1;
        } else {
            maxblocks_x = Math.ceil(width_r) * 2;
        }

        if ((height_r * 2) % 2 == 0) {
            maxblocks_y = Math.ceil(height_r - .5) * 2 + 1;
        } else {
            maxblocks_y = Math.ceil(height_r) * 2;
        }

        final List<String> lines = Lists.newArrayList();

        for (double y = -maxblocks_y / 2 + 1; y <= maxblocks_y / 2 - 1; y++) {
            final StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

            for (double x = -maxblocks_x / 2 + 1; x <= maxblocks_x / 2 - 1; x++) {
                if (shouldBeFilled(x, y, width_r, ratio)) {
                    System.out.println(
                            String.format("Section id for x: %s and y: %s is %s", x, y, getSectorNumber(x, y, width_r, 12))
                    );
                    line.append("█");
                }
            }
            lines.add(line.toString());
        }
        return lines;
    }

    private int getSectorNumber(final double x, final double y, final double radius, final int sectorAmount) {
        final double degreesPerSector = 360 / sectorAmount;
        final double rad = Math.atan2(y, x);
        final double degrees = rad * (180 / Math.PI);

        System.out.println("rad: " + rad + ", degrees: " + degrees);

        for (int i = 0; i < sectorAmount; i++) {
            final double startDegrees = degreesPerSector * i;
            final double endDegrees = startDegrees + degreesPerSector;

            if (degrees >= startDegrees && degrees <= endDegrees) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private double distance(final double x, final double y, final double ratio) {
        return Math.sqrt((Math.pow(y * ratio, 2)) + Math.pow(x, 2));
    }

    private boolean shouldBeFilled(final double x, final double y, final double radius, final float ratio) {
        return distance(x, y, ratio) <= radius;
    }
```

**My solution:**

The code I had in my getSectionNumber was already going in the right direction, I ended up just adding 180 ° so it got in range of 0-360. Here is the code I ended up with:

```java
package com.dbsoftwares.dangerwheel.hologram;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

import java.util.List;

public class HologramCircle {

    private final int height;
    private final int width;

    public HologramCircle(final int height, final int width) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public List<String> getLines() {
        final float width_r = (float) width / 2;
        final float height_r = (float) height / 2;
        final float ratio = width_r / height_r;

        final double maxblocks_x;
        final double maxblocks_y;

        if ((width_r * 2) % 2 == 0) {
            maxblocks_x = Math.ceil(width_r - .5) * 2 + 1;
        } else {
            maxblocks_x = Math.ceil(width_r) * 2;
        }

        if ((height_r * 2) % 2 == 0) {
            maxblocks_y = Math.ceil(height_r - .5) * 2 + 1;
        } else {
            maxblocks_y = Math.ceil(height_r) * 2;
        }

        final List<String> lines = Lists.newArrayList();

        for (double y = -maxblocks_y / 2 + 1; y <= maxblocks_y / 2 - 1; y++) {
            final StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

            for (double x = -maxblocks_x / 2 + 1; x <= maxblocks_x / 2 - 1; x++) {
                if (shouldBeFilled(x, y, width_r, ratio)) {
                    final int sector = getSectorNumber(x, y, 12);

                    line.append(ChatColor.values()[sector].toString());
                    line.append("█");
                }
            }
            lines.add(line.toString());
        }
        return lines;
    }

    private int getSectorNumber(final double x, final double y, final int sectorAmount) {
        final double degreesPerSector = 360 / sectorAmount;
        final double rad = Math.atan2(y, x);
        final double degrees = rad * (180 / Math.PI) + 180;

        for (int i = 0; i < sectorAmount; i++) {
            final double startDegrees = degreesPerSector * i;
            final double endDegrees = startDegrees + degreesPerSector;

            if (degrees >= startDegrees && degrees <= endDegrees) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private double distance(final double x, final double y, final double ratio) {
        return Math.sqrt((Math.pow(y * ratio, 2)) + Math.pow(x, 2));
    }

    private boolean shouldBeFilled(final double x, final double y, final double radius, final float ratio) {
        return distance(x, y, ratio) <= radius;
    }
}
```

[This is my result now, it's not perfect, but this for sure fits my needs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCxej.png)

Comment: You've already got `degrees` as a number between -180 and +180.  Can't you just add 180, divide by 360, multiply by the number of sectors, and round down?  You'll probably want some special logic for when the number of degrees is very close to -180 or +180, because of rounding errors.

Comment: A circle is 2pi radians so compute the radians on the point and divide by the number of sectors.

Comment: Didn’t realise I was actually going in the right direction with my getSectorNumber method, I will try this out tomorrow! But it does sound more logic to me now.

Comment: Sure.  Hey take me seriously about the rounding errors though.  The whole combination of working with radians, converting to degrees, then rounding doubles to integers can introduce unexpected results, and possibly pull you into sector -1 or sector 12.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem It seems to work admirably now, I ended up keeping my loop, might not be the most performant option, but I think it's less susceptible to those unexpected results.

I edited my post by adding what I did to get it to work.